# Create "folders" in UITableView that push next UITableView with contents (infinite!)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to make a UITableView where you can create folders that push another tableview and show the folder contents. The table gets its data from a plist and is fully editable. I want to make it possible to create infinite folders, inside a folder, without needing to push an extra viewcontroller for every folder. Ive already seen this in several apps, I just would like to know how it is be the best way to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIViewController with table view with your custom 'folder' design. Declare in `.h` NSArray as datasource. Load this datasource into table view. When user select item from table remove all items from datasource and populate it with new items (from your plist). Reload table view.

I guess you are in need of custom UITableViewCell as well.

Main idea of this feature is how you organize you datasource plists. They should have a tree-structure.

Comment: Yeah, thats the easy way. But i That creates tons of problems. Theres no animation, theres no back button, I want to push a viewcontroller, but not and extra vc for every sub directory.

Comment: Just think about ifile, it offers exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: @Maxner, I don't see problems. Any animation can be added to UIView (cell is a view, table view as well), back butoon is UIView - you can add it whenever you want.